# Knowledge Graph Embedding with Deep learning

Tags: conv-neural-network, lstm, embedding

Helloo,I'm confused about something, given a knowledge graph and its embedding, some DL models such as CNN /DNN/LSTM are used as a predictor for a link prediction task. How is the model able to learn from those embedding? (e.g. as CNN are usually used for images ... ) Do you have any clear explanation of how its working?